# Retaining tufte-handout footnote formatting with biblatex-chicago

Tags: tufte, biblatex-chicago

I'd like to use the `biblatex-chicago` package in a `tufte-handout` document.

Footnotes in `tufte-handout` documents normally look like this:

[image: Normal tufte-handout footnote]

(unindented, with the footnote number in superscript)

When I use the `biblatex-chicago` package, I get:

[image: tufte-handout footnote with biblatex-chicago]

(indented, with the footnote number on the baseline followed by a period)

This is the case with footnotes generated using both `\footnote{}` and `\autocite{}`.

How can I use `biblatex-chicago` while retaining the original formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `biblatex-chicago` modifies the setup of the behaviour to come closer to CMS requirements. If you don't want that you can load `biblatex-chicago` with the `footmarkoff` option.

The [documentation of `biblatex-chicago`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) has some more details (p. 60)

> `footmarkoff`
>   Although the *Manual* (14.19) recommends specific formatting for footnote (and endnote) marks, i.e., superscript in the text and in-line in foot- or endnotes, Charles Schaum
>   has brought it to my attention that not all publishers follow this practice, even when requiring Chicago style. I have retained this formatting as the default setup, but if you include the `footmarkoff` option, `biblatex-chicago-notes` will not alter LaTeX’s (or the `endnote` package’s) defaults in any way, leaving you free to follow the specifications of your publisher.
>   I have placed all of this code in `biblatex-chicago.sty`, so if you load the package with a call to `biblatex` instead, then once again footnote marks will revert to the
>   LaTeX default, but of course you also lose a fair amount of other formatting, as well. See section 4.5.1, below.

```
\documentclass[british,nobib]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, footmarkoff]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Unmodified footnote setup.]